# What are the module related files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, python-module

I don't have `pip` or `pipenv`, can't install until I follow a long approval process to get these tools. I know that under site-packages/dist-packages the relevant files are stored for a given module (whether it's written in C or Python etc).

I'm trying to find, what are the actual `requests` (2.18.4) module level files that we get after we install it (either via `pip` or `pipenv` or `python setup .` way).

Comment: I'll wait / dig for the answer here but one of the main reason was to find out file(s) which I can give them to the screening team, before this module can be installed in any machine. As `pip / pipenv` can install a module or the corresponding `.whl` file, the issue was we didn't want to install anything until it was screened for. My idea was if I could find the list of `requests` module related installed files (then I can give those files to the screening team for checking any violations/security issues/malware etc). It seems like, there's one other way: `requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=eb9be71cc41fd73a51a7c9cd1adde5de